# Why is using list() critical for .dots = setNames() uses in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am calling mutate using dynamic variable names. An example that mostly works is:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)
func <- function(a,b){
  return(a+b)
}
var1 = 'a'
var2 = 'b'
expr <- interp(~func(x, y), x = as.name(var1), y = as.name(var2))
new_name <- "dynamically_created_name"
temp <- df %>% mutate_(.dots = setNames(expr, nm = new_name))
```

Which produces

```
temp
  a b func(a, b)
1 1 1          2
2 2 2          4
3 3 3          6
4 4 4          8
5 5 5         10
```

This is mostly fine except that set names ignored the nm key. This is solved by wrapping my function in list():

```
temp <- df %>% mutate_(.dots = setNames(list(expr), nm = new_name))
temp
  a b dynamically_created_name
1 1 1                        2
2 2 2                        4
3 3 3                        6
4 4 4                        8
5 5 5                       10
```

My question is why is setNames ignoring it's key in the first place, and how does list() solve this problem?

Answer (score 10):

As noted in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36069043/1084259), the .dots argument is assumed to be a list, and setNames is a convenient way to rename elements in a list.

What is the .dots argument doing? Let's first think about the actual dots `...` argument. It is a series of expressions to be evaluated. Below the dots `...` are the two named expressions `c = ~ a * scale1` and `d = ~ a * scale2`.

```
scale1 <- -1
scale2 <- -2

df %>% 
  mutate_(c = ~ a * scale1, d = ~ a * scale2)
#>   a b  c   d
#> 1 1 1 -1  -2
#> 2 2 2 -2  -4
#> 3 3 3 -3  -6
#> 4 4 4 -4  -8
#> 5 5 5 -5 -10
```

We could just bundle those expressions together beforehand in a list. That's where .dots comes in. That parameter lets us tell `mutate_` to evaluate the expressions in the list.

```
bundled <- list(
  c2 = ~ a * scale1, 
  d2 = ~ a * scale2
)

df %>% 
  mutate_(.dots = bundled)
#>   a b c2  d2
#> 1 1 1 -1  -2
#> 2 2 2 -2  -4
#> 3 3 3 -3  -6
#> 4 4 4 -4  -8
#> 5 5 5 -5 -10
```

If we want to programmatically update the names of the expressions in the list, then setNames is a convenient way to do that. If we want to programmatically mix and match constants and variable names when making expressions, then the lazyeval package provides convenient ways to do that. Below I do both to create a list of expressions, name them, and evaluate them with `mutate_`

```
# Imagine some dropdown boxes in a Shiny app, and this is what user requested
selected_func1 <- "min"
selected_func2 <- "max"
selected_var1 <- "a"
selected_var2 <- "b"

# Assemble expressions from those choices
bundled2 <- list(
  interp(~fun(x), fun = as.name(selected_func1), x = as.name(selected_var1)),
  interp(~fun(x), fun = as.name(selected_func2), x = as.name(selected_var2))
)
bundled2
#> [[1]]
#> ~min(a)
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> ~max(b)

# Create variable names
exp_name1 <- paste0(selected_func1, "_", selected_var1)
exp_name2 <- paste0(selected_func2, "_", selected_var2)

bundled2 <- setNames(bundled2, c(exp_name1, exp_name2))
bundled2
#> $min_a
#> ~min(a)
#> 
#> $max_b
#> ~max(b)

# Evaluate the expressions
df %>% 
  mutate_(.dots = bundled2)
#>   a b min_a max_b
#> 1 1 1     1     5
#> 2 2 2     1     5
#> 3 3 3     1     5
#> 4 4 4     1     5
#> 5 5 5     1     5
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the tutorial I needed to wrap my head around what dots and seNames were doing.

Answer (score 2):

From `vignettes("nse")`:

> If you also want to output variables to vary, you need to pass a list of quoted objects to the `.dots` argument

So perhaps the reason why

```
temp <- df %>% mutate_(.dots = setNames(expr, nm = new_name))
```

Doesn't do what you want is, while you successfully set the name attribute here, `expr` is still a formula, not a list:

```
foo <- setNames(expr, nm = new_name)
names(foo) #"dynamically_created_name" "" 
class(foo) #"formula"
```

So if you make it a list, it works as expected:

```
expr <- interp(~func(x, y), x = as.name(var1),
               y = as.name(var2))
df %>% mutate_(.dots = list(new_name = expr))
  a b new_name
1 1 1        2
2 2 2        4
3 3 3        6
4 4 4        8
5 5 5       10
```

Comment: WAIT that's not quite it! that replaces the column name with `new_name` but we want to replace it with its *value*!

Comment: This actually raises some additional questions. I think the core of my issue is that I don't fully understand the syntax or functionality of .dots. Is there documentation or a vignette that handles it in more detail outside the "nse" vignette?

Comment: there is `vignette("lazyeval")` also